# I need help in Rewrite ruld

Tags: .htaccess

Orginal link = https://api.thekashmirmonitor.net/index.php/posts?categories=192

I want it in https://api.thekashmirmonitor.net/posts?categories=192

here in rewrite i just want to remove index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review these guidelines [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and add an explanation. Thank you.

Comment: This answer appears to be adding rather than removing "index.php".

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This answer appears to be adding rather than removing "index.php".